# Parent collapses when expanding child using toggle and page scrolls to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I asked two questions related to my current problem, but the way I asked and the code that I provided wasn't been enough to solve it, so I present the problem (that was raised from the previous solutions attempts) in a more complete way on this code snippet.

Basically I want this PHP generated file tree to expand/collapse the way it should. With the JQuery code that some nice people here at SO provided me it's almost solved.

The problem is now that when you expand a child the parent collapses, you will see this running the code below.

**Notes**:
-I'm using Wordpress and for some reason you need to make sure that the tree is collapsed at first, otherwise it's displayed fully expanded.
-I have a **related side problem**: When you click to toggle, the scroll goes all the way up.

```js
function init_php_file_tree() {

$('.pft-directory')  
  .on('click', function() {
     $(this).children('ul').toggle();
  })
  .children("ul").hide();
};
jQuery(init_php_file_tree);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head> 

  <body>

  <ul class="file">
    <ul>
      <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Parent Directory</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">somefile.pdf
                <ul></ul> <!-- this HTML code is generated from a php recursive function you will see it a lot (I'll fix that later)  -->
              </li>
              <li class="pft-file ext-doc">somefile2.doc
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Another parent directory</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-file ext-docx">V1.docx
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory 2</a>
                <ul>
                  <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">V2.pdf
                    <ul></ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="pft-file ext-png">HH-V1.png
                    <ul></ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
              <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory</a>
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">HH-V1.pdf
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory 3</a>
                <ul>
                  <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">HH-V1.pdf
                    <ul></ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
              <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory 4</a>
                <ul>
                  <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">HH-V1.pdf
                    <ul></ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>

        
  </body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the bubbling that occurs by using `event.stopPropagation()` (https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

Regarding your second problem, that the page scrolls up, that is very likely due to your `a href="#"`'s. Replace them with url's or use `a href="javascript:;"`.

Example below:

```js
function init_php_file_tree() {

$('.pft-directory')  
  .on('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     $(this).children('ul').toggle();
  })
  .children("ul").hide();
};
jQuery(init_php_file_tree);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head> 

  <body>

  <ul class="file">
    <ul>
      <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Parent Directory</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">somefile.pdf
                <ul></ul> <!-- this HTML code is generated from a php recursive function you will see it a lot (I'll fix that later)  -->
              </li>
              <li class="pft-file ext-doc">somefile2.doc
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Another parent directory</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-file ext-docx">V1.docx
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory 2</a>
                <ul>
                  <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">V2.pdf
                    <ul></ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="pft-file ext-png">HH-V1.png
                    <ul></ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
              <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory</a>
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">HH-V1.pdf
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory 3</a>
                <ul>
                  <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">HH-V1.pdf
                    <ul></ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
              <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory 4</a>
                <ul>
                  <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">HH-V1.pdf
                    <ul></ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>

        
  </body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect solution for both problems. Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is when you are clicking on child node it's click event is pass to it's parent node so you have to stop that passing. and for doing so you have to use `stopPropagation()` which will not pass event to it's parent element. For more info on `stopPropagation()` see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
function init_php_file_tree() {

$('.pft-directory')
  .on('click', function(e) {
     $(this).children('ul').toggle();
     e.stopPropagation();
  })
  .children("ul").hide();;
};
jQuery(init_php_file_tree);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head> 

  <body>

  <ul class="file">
    <ul>
      <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Parent Directory</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">somefile.pdf
                <ul></ul> <!-- this HTML code is generated from a php recursive function you will see it a lot (I'll fix that later)  -->
              </li>
              <li class="pft-file ext-doc">somefile2.doc
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Another parent directory</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-file ext-docx">V1.docx
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory 2</a>
                <ul>
                  <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">V2.pdf
                    <ul></ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="pft-file ext-png">HH-V1.png
                    <ul></ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
              <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory</a>
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">HH-V1.pdf
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory 3</a>
                <ul>
                  <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">HH-V1.pdf
                    <ul></ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
              <li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Child directory 4</a>
                <ul>
                  <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">HH-V1.pdf
                    <ul></ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>

        
  </body> 

</html>
```